# Yii related blank instance in view

Tags: database, activerecord, yii

Suppose we have three AR tables:

- product
- property
- property_value

Each table has relations to others, so property table have foreign key to product table, therefore property_value table have foreign key to property table.

How could I display all related tables in the view if all AR tables are empty?

```
$product = new Product();
$this->render('update', array('model' => $product));
```

Now in the view

```
foreach($model->property as $propertyModel) {
    echo $form->textField($propertyModel, 'name');
}
```

But if products model is new, it has no property-related instance.

Of course we can create new instances of all related tables and put it in view, but I think there may be a better way to do this.
Maybe Yii has some method like `getBlankRelated()`. Did I miss something?

Comment: If the tables are empty, what is the purpose that you want to display them?

Comment: because the logic is that we needs to save all related tables.
I just don't want to create new instance of related tables in controller. As an option I can create method to get blank related tables from main table, but whether it is correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is for creating new records, you can make a realtion in your product model like:

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
         ....
        'property'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Product','Product_id'),
    );
}

//you can access property in a lazy approach, Yii creates the property for you
foreach($model->property as $propertyModel) {
   echo $form->textField($propertyModel, 'name');
}
```

more details are [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship)

Comment: It helpful for property model, thank you a lot. 
But I need to create property-value model too, and if property model is already exist, property-value is empty because it BELONGS_TO product model and property model, so I need to create an array of new property-value instances to display it forms in view. How can I create all of this instances?

Comment: it is the same logic, create the same relation in your property model and refers it to property_value model.